# How to represent as an Entity framework query

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

How to represent this as an Entity Framework query syntax?

```
SELECT matiere_premiere.`code`,
       matiere_premiere.`designation`,
       matiere_premiere.`unite`,
       matiere_premiere.`frns` ,
       IF(ISNULL(REQ.qte), '0.00', REQ.qte) AS qte
FROM matiere_premiere 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT qte,matiere_premiere_code 
    FROM stock_mp JOIN matiere_premiere 
    ON matiere_premiere.`code` = matiere_premiere_code 
    WHERE DATE <= CURRENT_DATE() 
    ORDER BY DATE DESC 
     ) AS REQ ON REQ.matiere_premiere_code = matiere_premiere.`code`
GROUP BY matiere_premiere.`code` 
ORDER BY matiere_premiere.`code`
```

Comment: I tried that but I know what to do next at the group by:

Comment: var query = from mp in model.matiere_premiere
                        join req in
                            (from stk in model.stock_mp
                             join ms in model.matiere_premiere
                             on stk.matiere_premiere_code equals
                             ms.code
                             where stk.date <= DateTime.Today
                             orderby stk.date descending

Comment: select new { stk.qte, stk.matiere_premiere_code })
                        on mp.code equals req.matiere_premiere_code
                        group mp by new { mp.code } into grp
                        orderby grp.Key
                        select new
                        {
                            grp.Key,
                            grp.First().designation,

                        };

Comment: model is the context

Comment: You could use Linq expression or Lamba expression to write query in entity framework.

Comment: can you give me an example? I'm a little beginner in C #

Comment: Is this even a valid SQL statement? There's a GroupBy, but no aggregate functions in the select statement - that should not work...

Comment: Is this SQL Server/T-SQL? What are the data types? As mentioned above, all fields except `code` need an aggregate function - SUM for example. Get the SQL correct first and then look at LINQ/Lambda query.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, it is untested though. You might want to look into LinqPad

```
var now = DateTime.Now;

from m in matiere_preiere
join req in 
(from s in stock_mp
 join m2 in matire_preimere on s.code equals m2.matire_preiere_code
 where s.Date <= now
 select new {qte, matirere_premiere_code}) 
on req.matirere_premiere_code equals m.code into reql
from req in reql.DefaultIfEmpty()
order by m.code
select new {m.code, m.designation, m.unite,m.frns, qte=req.qte ?? 0.00}
```